# Unregister the receiver in the receiver code

Tags: java, final

Good day, I have the android sms sent and delivery receivers dynamically built, I am receiving a leakage error as I need to unregistered the receiver before switching the activity. I want to unregistered the receiver when it receives its response.

Moreover I cannot override the onPause and resume as this class is a library and extends dialog and the receivers have to be constructed in the code.

Here is the code:

```
private void sendSMS(String msg, String msisdn, String func) { 

   String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
   String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";
   log("SMS FUNCTION: RUN");


    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0,
           new Intent(SENT), 0);

    PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0,
           new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

    BroadcastReceiver smsReceiverD=new BroadcastReceiver(){

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            log("SMS FUNCTION: SMS DELIVER CHECK");
            switch (getResultCode())
            {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    sendEventLog("Failed(SMS not delivered)"); 
                    break;
            }
        }

    };

    BroadcastReceiver smsReceiverS=new BroadcastReceiver(){

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            log("SMS FUNCTION: SEND CHECK");

            switch (getResultCode())
            {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                    log("Failed(Generic failure)");
                    sendEventLog("moFailed(Generic failure)");  
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                    sendEventLog("Failed(No service)");     
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                    sendEventLog("Failed(Null PDU)");   
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                    sendEventLog("Failed(Radio off)");  
                    break;
            }
        }

    };

   SmsManager MySmsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
   sendEventLog("Send("+keyword+":"+msisdn+")");         

   if (msg != null) {
    log("SMS FUNCTION: SMS SEND");
       MySmsManager.sendTextMessage(msisdn, null, keyword, sentPI, deliveredPI);
       mContext.registerReceiver(smsReceiverD,new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));
       mContext.registerReceiver(smsReceiverS,new IntentFilter(SENT));
    }
   }
```

I want to add

```
mContext.unregisterReceiver(smsReceiverS);
```

In the smsReciverS.

It says

```
Cannot refer to a non-final variable smsReceiverS inside an inner class defined in a different method
```

and if I do make it final:

```
The local variable smsReceiverS may not have been initialized
```

Please can someone help.

Comment: You should edit your question and provide full non-working code

Comment: WHy can't you override classes from the library? Are they final?

Answer (score 0):

Well use `arg0.unregister(this);` where `arg0` is instanceof `Context` inside your `onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1)` method of `smsReceiverS`

Answer (score 0):

I think in this situation you could use `Handler` and `Runnable` task to unregister you receiver:

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

....

private Runnable unregisterIt = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        mContext.unregisterReceiver(smsReceiverS);
    }
};

...
//to unregister just call this
mHanler.post(unregisterIt);
```

Comment: Its telling me the receiver leaked when it registers it?

Comment: @David Necraft what do you mean under "leaked"? and please formulate your question better that previous comment, because i really don't understand what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

While Waqas' solution is definitely possible (onReceive() will be called with the context the receiver runs in), and Evos' solution makes no sense to me (the code assumes, by calling `Handler()`, that it runs in the exact context where it is then later supposed to run), both answers do not address the original question, which is about an error regarding a final variable.

The point is that you need to make mContext final so it won't change for your on-the-fly BroadcastReceiver, which will carry an implicit reference to it because it is an anonymous inner class. However, restricitions apply regarding final variables; they must be initialized exactly once.

The analysis to enforce this is run at compile-time and has no deeper knowledge of Android mechanisms, so all that counts is the declaration, the constructor, and further use down the road.

Presumably, you're declaring

```
Activity mContext = null;
```

which leads to the error later because then you assign a value a second time?

Although Waqas' solution will work, if you want to understand `final`, and my assumption is wrong, you'll have to update your Q with code snippets regarding the use of `mContext`.